# Want to know the mac id's currently connected with my binatone router?

Tags: router, wireless-router, internet-filter

I want to know in my binatone router how many systems are currently connected and mac address.
In that router I want to restrict the internet connections for android mobile devices.

Comment: Which Binatone router?

Comment: Binatone 850W ADSL from airtel.

Answer (score 2):

Interface Setup -> LAN -> Under DHCP: "Current Pool Summary" button opening a new browser window in my Binatone DT 850W. But it's keeping the devices in the list even if the device is disconnected, till the router is restarted and I think till expiry time; while I'm thinking my Asus DSL-N10E router shows only the currently connected devices instead of keeping sticky record like that.

(Edit: My wireless printer isn't showing in the list, it used to show in Asus DSL-N10E)

> I want to restrict the internet connections for android mobile
>   devices.

I've seen option in Android mobiles to show their MAC address.

For restricting a MAC, I'm thinking: "Interface Setup" -> Wireless -> At the bottom there's option of filtering MACs.

Answer (score 0):

Which Binatone router are you using?  From windows, you could write a quick script to ping every IP in your range (196.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.255 or similar) and then run the arp -a command on your computer which will give you a list of all mac addresses you have connected to?

Alternatively, your router may have ARP enabled which will allow you to see - or the DHCP scope on your router may even show you.

Also, [I've used this tool](https://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/) in the past which helps you to look at all host names, ips and MACs registered on your network.

You can then use MAC address filtering on your router to only allow certain devices out to the net - but without a router model number, I can only give vague advice.

Comment: My router model number is Binatone 850W ADSL from airtel